# Parse PFFile Error - Trying to get an image file (Swift2)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to get an image file through this code bellow.

```
let anotherPhoto : PFObject = PFObject(className: "Menu")

        let userImageFile = anotherPhoto["photo"] as! PFFile
        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                }
            }
        }
```

But It always happens this error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Opcional value
```

This error appears in that line

```
let userImageFile = anotherPhoto["photo"] as! PFFile
```

Is there something wrong at the code?

Comment: You haven't actually retrieved `anotherPhoto` from Parse, so the object will be empty. This means that the `photo` key will be nil but you say `as! PFFile` - the as! says "this value won't be nil". So you get an exception

Comment: Oh! I see! But how I may retrieve anotherPhoto? Using PFQuery? @Paulw11

Comment: Yes. A query or fetch operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@paulw is right. you have to first fetch your objects or records from parse and then you can get file from parse if any.

You can follow below code (Note: This code is in objective-C):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"DataTable"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            if ([objects count] > 0 ) {
                PFObject *obj = [(NSArray*)objects objectAtIndex:0];
                PFFile *file = obj[@"FileField"];
                [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *Data, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error)
                    {
                        // write the downloaded file to documents dir

                        [Data writeToFile:strlocalFilePath atomically:YES];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@" error...... %@",error);
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

Hope this might help you.